# In Android Studio my arrays.xml file that contains multiple string arrays gives a mergeDebugResources FAILED exception

Tags: arrays, xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

xml file named arrays.xml which contains multiple string arrays. When I try to compile Android Studio gives an Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. Here's my file what is wrong with it? I'm sure this file is he problem I tried every other resource in a different project only when I included this file problem occured.
I can't add my file to here as a code sample because it exceeds character limits.

I uploaded it to google drive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d_LiL4YopDNySYuCjOB-O5TnAcr_k3K8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i had error on this symbol ' in the list array_iw  and array_uk so pls try to replace 
<item>В'єтнамська</item> to <item>В\'єтнамська</item>,  
 <item>צ'כית</item>  to   <item>צ\'כית</item>
    <item>גוג'ראטי</item> to <item>גוג\'ראטי</item>

Comment: Thank you your answer is correct. Thanks for the help.